# SQL insert into a table after a query

Tags: mysql

So I am not sure how to approach this. I have a table that looks like this 
[enter image description here][1]

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9Cl7.png

I need to take information from a different table and insert it into the above table.

The query to get the information that I need is as follows:

```
select customerNumber, sum(quantityOrdered * priceEach) as orderTotal, curdate() as todaysDate 
from orders join orderdetails

where orders.orderNumber = orderdetails.orderNumber

group by orders.customerNumber

having orderTotal > 150000
```

I have tried using the:

```
insert into topCustomers( customerNumber, orderTotal, curdate())
```

before my select query and that is not how it is supposed to work.

Any guidance would be amazing !!

Thank you all in advanced

Answer (score 3):

In the parentheses of your `INSERT INTO` statement you put the FIELD NAMES to which you are inserting. You don't have a field name called `CURDATE()` and so the query is failing. Instead:

```
insert into topCustomers( customerNumber, orderTotal, CustomerDate) 
select customerNumber, sum(quantityOrdered * priceEach) as orderTotal, curdate() as todaysDate 
from orders join orderdetails    
where orders.orderNumber = orderdetails.orderNumber    
group by orders.customerNumber    
having orderTotal > 150000
```

Example:

```
mysql> create table test2 (cdate date);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.32 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test2 (curdate());
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual tcorresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cte())' at line 1

mysql> INSERT INTO test2 (cdate) SELECT curdate();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: `CURDATE()` usage is fine. It just returns the current date value

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya it is not fine. You can only put field names inside the parantheses at that location. You could put `CURDATE()` if you were using the `VALUES` keyword.

Comment: Ok Thanks. something new - worth knowing +1

Comment: Thank you very much JNevill!